# Show that if $f \cup g$ is a bijection then $(f \cup g)^{-1}$ = $f^{-1} \cup g^{-1}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Seeking help on a proof of this condition.

We're assuming that $f \cup g$ is a function from $A \cup C$ to $B \cup D$.

Let $x \in A \cup C$ be arbitrary. Then $x\in A$ or $x \in C$.

If $x \in A$, then $f(x) \in B$. So $f^{-1}(x) \in A$?

(Also: If $x\in C$ then $f(x) \in D$.)

I know the definition of an inverse function: $f^{-1} = \left\{(b,a) \in B \times A \mid (a,b) \in f \right\}$, but I'm not sure how to incorporate it here.

Comment: Here's a start - if $(y,x)\in (f\cup g)^{-1}\Rightarrow (x,y)\in f\cup g$. What can you say then? Can you somehow show $(y,x)\in f^{-1}\cup g^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1):

For *any* set $a$ we can define:$$a^{-1}:=\{\langle y,x\rangle\mid\langle x,y\rangle\in a\}$$

Evidently $$\langle y,x\rangle\in a^{-1}\iff\langle x,y\rangle\in a$$

and based on this it can be deduced that: $$\langle y,x\rangle\in\left(f\cup g\right)^{-1}\iff\langle y,x\rangle\in f^{-1}\cup g^{-1}$$

So $\left(f\cup g\right)^{-1}=f^{-1}\cup g^{-1}$.

Caution: in this context $a$ being a function is no guarantee for $a^{-1}$ to be a function. However, if $a$ is a bijection then so is $a^{-1}$. Also if $a$ is a bijection then every subset of $a$ is a bijection.